# Unsupported operand between str and int

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working with beautifulsoup (from bs4). I am getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`. I have checked all the previous answers in Stackoverflow but nothing worked.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, 'html5lib')
texts = soup.findAll('p')
visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
article = ""
for text in visible_texts:
    article += text.decode('utf-8')
 ... other codes
```

I am getting the error in `article += text.decode('utf-8')` line. I don't understand where is **int** in the code. The variable article is declared as string before the loop. text.decode(...) returns a string in the requested encoding.

> visible in filter argument is a custom function and htmltext is
>   request.get() method **text** object.

Any clarification would be helpful.

---

The below the next few lines of code that come outside the for loop immediately following the article object concatnation.

```
 article = str(article)
 article = BeautifulSoup(article, features='html5lib')
 print('\n\n\n', article, '\n\n\n')
 article = str(article).replace("\n", " ")
```

[Full code is available here in case required.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-pxyiIb1jROCKBd0C6SiwqO25hFBZHX8)

Comment: the state of `article ` is string. and here's the point `text.decode('utf-8')` where I believe that `text` isn't `string` because `str` have no method `decode` , check [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp) , are you dealing with `Unicode` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη  .decode() is a method of bytes() type. the request object 's text method returns objects in bytes format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misleading us, because you did not include the stacktrace, which is telling a different story. When testing your code, I got the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 32, in main
    article += text.decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\python-3.7\env\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1559, in decode
    indent_space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

So, it's not the addition in your code that is raising the exception, but a subtraction in the bs4 code.

The reason that you get this exception is that you call `decode()` using incorrect arguments. It is defined as follows:

```py
decode(indent_level=None, eventual_encoding='utf-8', formatter='minimal')
```

So the `text.decode('utf-8')` from your code is equivalent to `text.decode(indent_level='utf-8')` and that doesn't make sense, hence the exception.

You can fix the error using either:

```py
article += text.decode(eventual_encoding='utf-8')
```

or

```py
article += text.decode(None, 'utf-8')
```

PS: Next time please include the stacktrace in your question ;-)